# Custom functions by pages in NSIS disappear

Tags: nsis

I have the following script:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE ComponentPost
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW  DirectoryShow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DirectoryLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Unfortunately, after the first directory selection dialog, directory page returns to default, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple directory pages you also normally want to store the selected paths in different variables:

```
Var SomeOtherFolder
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $SomeOtherFolder
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
...
Section
SetOutPath $SomeOtherFolder
File /r "c:\otherfiles"
Section
```

All of this information can be found in the [Modern UI readme](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html)...